# Firebase Hosting - Accessing API's?

Tags: php, api, firebase-hosting

If we're using Firebase hosting, how would we access someone's API without server-side scripts like php?

Comment: JavaScript AJAX calls?

Comment: Apparently the API I'm trying to access has issues with CORS and they say it must be accessed server-side

Comment: Server-side meaning only from a firebase-hosted server?

Comment: The site is an Angular Site, I deployed it to firebase hosting, but can't figure out a way to execute something server-side (to avoid all the cross-site issues). I did it, but only by moving all my files to another host. But if there's something I'm overlooking, and I can still execute scripts on a firebase server than I'd rather stick with Firebase for speed and convenience

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to execute server-side? In general it seems absurd if Angular etc. couldn't send server-side requests. In any case, have you looked into this one: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out how to do it using php.

Comment: Can you add more details? I am planning to create an express site and call APIs hosted on Heroku? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Firebase hosting only hosts static files. So in order to call external api, you've to do it from JavaScript using fetch/axios or something like that. However, if the api endpoint hasn't enabled [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for your domain, your browser doesn't allow to make that request for security.